# OutOfMemoryException при компиляции в VS 2008

Tags: wpf, xaml, visual-studio, c#

Забавная ошибка в VS 2008: если я собираю проект WPF с очень большими XAML-файлами, то во время второй компиляции, после открытия, проект VS падает. Лечится перезапуском VS. Может можно в настройках указать использовать диск? Также у меня есть подозрения, что падает она из-за большой вложенности элементов. Возможно ли такое?

Comment: А что диспетчер задач показывает по поводу использования памяти студией?

Comment: На борту 3Гб ОЗУ, VS съедает в режиме редактирования 500 метров, при компилировании около 1,5 Гб.

Comment: Вопрос-то не в этом. Раз Вы говорите, что проблема только после второй компиляции — сколько памяти съедено в начале, сколько съедается во время первой компиляции? По идее-то после того как первая компиляция закончилась, память должна вернуться на место. Иначе это утечка в Студии и помочь Вам нечем.

Comment: И да, сколько же эти XAML файлы весят? /* Out of memory при компиляции я как-то вообще ни разу не ловил, но слышал, что довольно несложно его добиться с помощью boost'а =). */

Answer (score 2):

Во избежании таких проблем установи на VS2008 сервис пак второй :))) 
*Если сам не найдешь, отпишись, залью на сервак, дам ссылку (весит прилично - предупреждаю)*

Answer (score 0):

Как это использовать диск? Для чего? Конечно нельзя. Если падает во время второй компиляции и лечится перезапуском, то это означает утечку ресурсов. Это баг в студии. Вы можете попытаться увеличить какой-нибудь лимит памяти, но он всё равно быстро исчерпается.

Comment: Использовать диск - это и значит увеличить лимит памяти за счет мапирования.

Comment: ОК. В любом случае это не поможет. Ну или поможет, но очень ненадолго.

Answer (score 0):

Во-пepвых, по возможности поставить 2010 студию. Это если действительно проблема в студии
или попробовать перeкомпилировать с другой версией .NET.